# How to get last 3 month name in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**My Query is**

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, IssueDate)) AS MonthName,
       ItemId,
       COUNT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, IssueDate, 6)) AS WorkingDays
FROM   dbo.Issue AS Issue
GROUP BY
       CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, IssueDate)),
       ItemId
HAVING (ItemId = 427)
```

**Query wise Show**
[image]

**but I need**

[image: but my need]

plz solved this everybody soon as possible.

Comment: I'm guessing that you say last 3 month what you mean is the last quarter of the year

Comment: If that is the case you can use `datepart(quarter,issuedate) = 4`

Comment: yes, I also concern on the requirement "last 3 month", is it the last quarter of the year? or the last 3 months which can be found in the table. e.g: the table only have JAN, FEB, MAR, APR data, so the last 3 months should be FEB, MAR and APR? or how? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry @Imrul Kaesh , there is some mistake on the query. I didn't filter the last 3 months by ItemId.

I have updated my query as below, please have a try:

```
WITH Last3Month AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 MONTH(IssueDate) AS Mth
    FROM Issue
    WHERE ItemId = 452      --Please add this WHERE Clause
    ORDER BY Mth DESC
)
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, IssueDate)) AS MonthName,
        ItemId,
        COUNT(CONVERT(varchar, IssueDate, 6)) AS WorkingDays
FROM dbo.Issue AS Issue
INNER JOIN Last3Month ON MONTH(Issue.IssueDate) = Last3Month.Mth
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, IssueDate)), ItemId, Last3Month.Mth
HAVING (ItemId = 452)
ORDER BY Last3Month.Mth
```

Comment: thanks @Doraemon, your Last answer is now worked. Dear Bro. now tale me-  it is `IssueDate` wise how to show? When issuedate wise Call then some Item not show. such as (ItemID=452 showon only **October** Month but need **October & September** ------------------------
**N.B. It can not in any way (View, Procedure) as U Like.**

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
    SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,IssueDate)           AS [MonthName],
           ItemId,
           COUNT(CONVERT(varchar, IssueDate, 6)) AS WorkingDays
    FROM    [dbo].[Issue]
    WHERE   IssueDate >= DATEADD (MM,-3,IssueDate)
    GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,IssueDate), ItemId
    HAVING  (ItemId = 427)
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont think this is work. The where condition is true for all single data. For example: the `IssueDate` of a data is 28/08/2015, `DATEADD (MM,-3,IssueDate)` is 28/05/2015, which is true for logic `IssueDate >= DATEADD (MM,-3,IssueDate)`. And so for all the data.
.

Comment: hey @Doraemon, now showing 4 month. `WITH Last3Month AS(SELECT DISTINCT TOP(3)MONTH(IssueDate) AS Mth FROM Issue AS Issue_1 ORDER BY Mth DESC)SELECT CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, Issue.IssueDate)) AS MonthName, Issue.ItemId, Last3Month_1.Mth FROM Issue AS Issue LEFT OUTER JOIN Last3Month AS Last3Month_1 ON MONTH(Issue.IssueDate) = Last3Month_1.Mth GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, Issue.IssueDate)), Issue.ItemId, Last3Month_1.Mth
HAVING (Issue.ItemId = 430)` Because this is  ‌`LEFT OUTER JOIN‌`. but i don't include `LEFT OUTER JOIN‌` then maximum Item showing 2 month. plz solve this.

Comment: @ Imrul Kaesh Few question here: 1. do you have record from different year? 2. You no need do the count for working hour? Can you provide your data set so that I can have a look on the result? As I am using my own testing data, so there might be some different. Thank you.

Comment: @Doraemon, How can do Provide my data? plz give me your Mail ID or any way

Comment: @Doraemon,  plz check my Database on the google drive (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_k-gFpZlM3JYkVfT1Z6dmJiUEk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if this is work on your side. I just simply create a table which is similar to your case and do the testing on my side.
Please have a try.

```
WITH Last3Month AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 MONTH(IssueDate) AS Mth
    FROM Issue
    ORDER BY Mth DESC
)
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, IssueDate)) AS MonthName,
        ItemId,
        COUNT(CONVERT(varchar, IssueDate, 6)) AS WorkingDays
FROM dbo.Issue AS Issue
INNER JOIN Last3Month ON MONTH(Issue.IssueDate) = Last3Month.Mth
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR, DATENAME(MONTH, IssueDate)), ItemId, Last3Month.Mth
HAVING (ItemId = 427)
ORDER BY Last3Month.Mth
```

Comment: Mr. Doraemon, Thank U for  assistance.

Comment: Hi @Imrul Kaesh , if this is the answer that you are looking for, please marks it as answer so that others people can have a reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok @Imrul Kaesh what is your problem now?

Based on the data set you provided, I used my query to select last 3 months records for ItemId=427 and ItemId=430. And the results shown as below:

[image]

Bear in mind that, you can only use INNER JOIN but not LEFT OUTER JOIN‌. Thank you.

Comment: plz try to **ItemId=452 and 460**, that is not properly  showing data.

Answer (score 0):

I am properly get **only month name** below query -

`SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, dt) AS Monthnames, ItemId
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (3) DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, IssueDate), 0) AS dt, ItemId
FROM dbo.Issue
WHERE (ItemId = 452)
ORDER BY dt DESC) AS t`[Now show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsXAS.png)

but my need  ItemID,ItemName, WorkingDays, IssueQty  and MonthNames
[my need this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw4z9.png)